# Best way of making the model discoverable in a RESTful endpoint?

Tags: http, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am looking to make the model that a RESTful endpoint expects to be discoverable.

For example:

My service expects a user model to be formed as such:

```
{
name:'',
role:2,
userId: 12345
}
```

To post a new user I would need to know the structure of this model to correctly send it in the body.

I do not want to enable static typing for the consumption of the service, but I do want a dynamic way for getting the structure of the model I expect so the client can reasonably adapt.

I want to adhere to the principles of REST as much as possible lest I incur the wrath of Mr. Roy Fielding, but I also need to get things done in a reasonably friendly manner.

I am not looking to just create documentation about the endpoint either.  I know many ways of doing so, but I want to be able to discover things pro grammatically.